# MongoDB: make $lookup put its output in objects inside an array

Tags: mongodb

### Problem

Say I have this document in a `project-storage` collection:

```
{
  name: 'storage',
  containers: [
    { name: 'container1', items: ['item1', 'item2'] },
    { name: 'container2', items: ['item2', 'item3'] },
  ],
}
```

And these in a `project-items` collection:

```
{ name: 'item1', value: 1 },
{ name: 'item2', value: 1 },
{ name: 'item3', value: 1 },
```

I want to write a query that reads the `storage` document and inlines the items of each `container` inside the container, to have this:

```
{
  name: 'storage',
  containers: [
    {
      name: 'container1',
      items: ['item1', 'item2'],
      _inlinedItems: [{ name: 'item1', value: 1 }, { name: 'item2', value: 1 }]
    },
    {
      name: 'container2',
      items: ['item2', 'item3'],
      _inlinedItems: [{ name: 'item2', value: 1 }, { name: 'item3', value: 1 }]
    },
  ],
}
```

---

### Failed attempt

Using an `aggregate` and the `$lookup` operator, I tried this:

```
[
  { $match: { name: 'storage' } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'project-items',
      localField: 'containers.items',
      foreignField: 'name',
      as: 'containers._inlinedItems',
    },
  },
]
```

Which does not work, because 1) it erases the `container` field completely and 2) it mixes the items from the two containers:

```
{
  name: 'storage',
  containers: {
    _inlinedItems: [{ name: 'item1', value: 1 }, { name: 'item2', value: 1 }, { name: 'item3', value: 1 }]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this for example by putting something special in the `as` field of the `$lookup` operator?

---

### Unsatisfactory solution

The best I could do is to `unwind` the `containers`, do the lookup and then `group` the documents back together:

```
[
  { $match: { name: 'storage' } },
  { $unwind: '$containers' },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'project-items',
      localField: 'containers.items',
      foreignField: 'name',
      as: 'containers._inlinedItems',
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id' ,
      name: { $first: '$name' },
      containers: { $push: '$containers' },
    },
  },
]
```

Which works, but I have to list all the properties from the storage document which I want to keep (for example `name` here), which is very problematic in my case since I do not know the names of all the properties, but I do need to keep them.

---

### Proper solution?

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to specify to the `$lookup` operator that I want it to write inside the `container` element it read the items from?
Or is the `unwind` + `group` the only way to do this?

Comment: grouping is the best solution, I could think of. If you don't have a large number of documents in your collection, I think this solution will work except that it is doing a collection scan and no index key used.     "executionStats" : { "executionSuccess" : true, "nReturned" : 1, "executionTimeMillis" : 0, "totalKeysExamined" : 0, "totalDocsExamined" : 1, "executionStages" : { "stage" : "COLLSCAN", "filter" : {

Comment: Hum, I didn't even think of the performances impact on mongo, all I had in mind was to move this operation from my application to mongo. I believe that this is fine for now, but I'll need to look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try without `$unwind`, I have not compared performance of both but you can check it, if this will help you,

- `$match` your condition
- `$lookup` with items and get in items array
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$map` on `containers` iterate loop and doo filter on items using `$filter` and check condition if match items then return in `_inlinedItems` and then merge objects with current index object using `$mergeObjects`

```
  { $match: { name: "storage" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "project-items",
      localField: "containers.items",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "items"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      containers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$containers",
          as: "c",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$c",
              {
                _inlinedItems: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$items",
                    cond: { $in: ["$$this.name", "$$c.items"] }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { items: 0 } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cyAlXq7w14y)

Comment: Ah yes, this is very good, I believe I managed to get what I want thanks to your explanation. I'm fairly new to mongo and don't know the operators well, in particular this way of using `$map` with `$mergeObjects`.

I replaced the `$project` operator with a `addFields` on `containers` so that I do not need to whitelist all my fields (`name` for example):

As far as I can tell, this works! Thanks! :-)

Comment: I also had to add an excluding filter to remove `items`: 
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ddgBECMoeA1)

Comment: Good you can use `$set` as well, i have updated that way, you can check.